# cannot connect to aws rds anymore

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am running a db.t2.micro instance on AWS RDS. I used to be able to connect to it via MySQL workbench, but now I can't anymore. Nothing has changed though.
I even re-entered the end point, admin name and password, even though they we're the same still, but still cannot connect.
My elastic beanstalk application that relies on the DB however can still access it. So I suspected the public access had been changed, but that's still enabled too.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Here is the error I am getting:
http://pgrbristol.org.uk/rant/DBError.PNG

I have checked all the points.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you able to ping the URL, when you ping that URL it will return an IP address, can you try giving that IP instead of hostname.

Comment: the firewall is blocking it maybe due to ip address (perhaps custom / Use My IP) setting in security settings? Need to refresh that?

Comment: Check your security group of AWS RDS machine whether it accepts connections other than Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Drew was right. Thank you! Needed to update my ip addres in the security settings. Since I don't have a static IP, it will change frequently. Is it save to just delete the old IPs in the security settings?